# To launch browser with Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, selenium, jenkins

Configured Jenkins (with Tomcat) on Win7 to launch my maven command. With My maven command i am launching selenium test scripts which launches web broswer and execute the test cases.

Problem: When i trigerrs build using Jenkins, build started and shows everything on Jenkins - Console. it even generates proper html report (which i set in my selenium java code). But everything happens in silent mode (without launching the browser)

Question: where and how to configure Jenkins/Tomcat to launch the browser?

Comment: Thnx for providing link: Quote from the mntnd link "
If you run Jenkins as a service in the background ..... You may either try to run it not as a service in the foreground, or run it as a Local System account and check Allow the service to interact with desktop option. In the latter case you may get into permission problems, though.

.. Jenkins Windows 'native' installation is not really native. It's a wrapper around Java that runs it as a service." This is fine but on the top of it, we have to install plug-in into Jenkins to launch browser. It worked for me to get an interactive session:)

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to set up a Selenium Grid. This would also allow you to test on different OS and browsers to that set up on your Jenkins box.

It also supports parallel testing if your test framework supports threads.

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2